# java.lang.RuntimeException: MediaMuxer creation failed

Tags: java, android

The following error occurs in android 9 version but all other version work perfectly.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: MediaMuxer creation failed`

Here is my java code.

```
String outputPath = mOutputPath;
Log.d(TAG, "output file is " + outputPath);

try {
    mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputPath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new RuntimeException("MediaMuxer creation failed", ioe);
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `outputPath` ?

Comment: out put path is video path

Comment: I mean what is the actual value? "output file is <what?>"

Comment: any solution plz?